# In JS, do class properties always have to be initialized? If not, how can I declare one without initialization?

Tags: javascript, class, initialization

I've just learned that class properties are declared and initialized like below:

```
Blog.prototype.signature = "Puzzler Ruby";
```

Can I declare it without initializing it, writing like `Blog.prototype.signature;` or something? And may I skip typing `.prototype`?

Comment: Can you please explain what you would hope to accomplish by declaring but not initializing? And no, you can't skip the `.prototype` if you want the `signature` to be inherited by the instances of `Blog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid initializing your class properties (if you want them to be inherited by the objects you create). Why not just initialize them with `null`?

To avoid writing `prototype` each time, see this cleaner syntactic sugar: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I recommend that people not use `class` syntax until they fully understand prototypal inheritance. It's a syntactic sugar which [hurts people learning the language](https://github.com/joshburgess/not-awesome-es6-classes).